# OBS studio start and stop shortcut-keys

Tags: shortcut-keys, obs-studio

I installed OBS studio version 25.0.3 on ubuntu 20.04 and want to make a youtube video by screen recording, but I don't want people to see when I click on stop record button in my video. So is it any shortcut-keys to stop recording the screen using OBS( or start recording)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Screen record]Solved, Just go to settings in OBS and hotkeys and I can make shortcut keys for start/stop recording! I am so dumb.